# Postback values missing after Viewstate moved to Database

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

Following advice from another post, I have moved my viewstate to a database instead of disabling it entriely. However, now that I have done so, when I post back a form with a dropdown box in where the items have been added dynamically, the value is empty (this was happening when I disabled the viewstate and is the reason I moved it to the DB)

Why is this happening? It was Ok when the viewstate was on the page so why would it stop working now the Viewstate is in the database?

Using .NET 2.0

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you disabling it in the first place and what version of ASP.NET are you on?

Comment: I am not disabling it. I have moved it to be stored in the database. I am using ASP.NET 2. I want to decrease page load times while keeping the viewstate. Storing it in the database allows me to do this.

Comment: How are you saving it in the db? What is your table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a life-cycle issue; you're probably not getting the ViewState back early enough, when the page expects it. Try loading the ViewState in the PageInit method and see if that fixes it?

Unless your ViewState is really large, I would keep it on the page. If you want to decrease page load times, start by adding a trace attribute to the page tag and see where any real bottle necks are (this will also give you the accurate ViewState size). Unless you're dealing with tens of thousands of records, the performance impact due to ViewState size should be acceptable.

**UPDATE**

Sample syntax for saving state of radio button selection:

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);

    if (ViewState["SomeValue"] != null)
        someValue = stringViewState["SomeValue"];
}


protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    ViewState["SomeValue"] = someValue;

    return base.SaveViewState();
}
```

Comment: When you say see where the bottlenecks are using trace, am I just looking at what takes the most space in the viewstate i.e biggest figure in viewstate column? BTW, Moving to PageInit Worked! Thanks.

Comment: One more thing. I have an update panel around some radio buttons and for some reason, this no longer works with the viewstate the way it is. When I click on one, I see the Ajax postback happen but my radio button isn't selected and from what I have seen, the code in the code behind isn't executed. Could this be a page cycle issue?

Comment: The trace will show you all the page events being called, including the one containing your DB call - it's just convenient to see a time line for everything at a glance and to check of maybe something else is causing the performance hit.

Comment: Not sure about the Ajax issue here because this adds another layer of complexity on it. If this was 4.0 you would have more granular options for managing ViewState on a control by control basis. I would opt to go without the update panel here - simplify it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't opt out of the update panel with this one :( Will keep researching and maybe rewrite it to work a different way. Thanks for the help, will mark as answer.

Comment: BTW, what are the radio buttons for? Are they triggering the DB call? You might be able to override LoadViewState and SaveViewState methods... but since the ViewState is on the DB this gets messy life-cycle-wise.

Comment: The radio buttons control some stock options on the page, i.e bag size ect. How would overriding the Load and Save help? Is it losing the viewstate it had with the posted value which is causing an issue?

Comment: Radio buttons do not save their selected state in ViewState properly. I usually override these two methods to do it myself. In your case you have the ViewState coming back from the DB in the PageInit so I'm not sure if this will work or not. Either way, I'm going to update my answer to give you some sample syntax, ok?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. I will have a play with the code :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are implementing it but the way I did it was to create a custom `PageStatePersister` and `PageAdapter`.  If you do it right, it just works.  Here is an article that gives an example of how to do it with this method.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1293397.aspx/1?Store+ViewState+in+the+Database+instead+of+Hidden+Form+Field

Matthew

Comment: Did you notice any change at all with postbacks, ajax forms ect? Atm I am just overriding the PageStatePersister property and sending a custom class in its place.